# string terminated by ^7

Tags: c#, sockets, color-codes, quake

I make a rcon request to a quake 3 server in C# using a udp socket and byte arrays for sending and receiving.

Everything works fine except that when I request a server status, the player names strings are all terminated by ^7, like this: DeathMaster^7.

None of the other strings returned by the rcon commands have this problem, so I am baffled as to what could be wrong.

If you know, please let me know.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code, or we'll have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code.

`^7` is a color code used for players to change the color of their names as they appear in onscreen text. In this case, `^7` sets the name to be white.

If you want to test this for yourself, connect to a server and change your name to something like this: `^3|SO|^7JonSkeet` and you'll see a name with multiple colors.

Many games are built off of the Quake3 engine, and thus they also use a similar system for colorizing names.

[Color codes of Quake3](http://www.wikihow.com/Color-Your-Name-in-Quake-3)

Answer (score 0):

It can be real name from db. And you can rewrite (cut last 2 character) in names from request in cycle.